# Why do same-charge particles repel each other? Would anti-particles exhibit the contrary behaviour?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, feynman-diagrams, antimatter, coulombs-law

Coulomb's Law states that same-charge particles repel each other and opposite-charge particles attract each other.

[image: Coulomb's Law Example - Repulsion & Attraction]

Coulomb's Law formula is:

[image: Coulomb's Law Formula]

This is related to Maxwell's equations:

[image: Maxwell's equations]

An example of an electromagnetic wave is:

[image: Electromagnetic wave]

Would anti-particles act the opposite as well in relation to the force repulsion and attraction?

[image: Anti-particles and anti-matter]

The real question is that if particles and anti-particles are really opposite, they would always attract and remain together.

> A Feynman diagram showing the annihilation of an electron and a positron (antielectron), creating a photon that later decays into an new electron–positron pair.

[image: Feynman diagram example]

Some examples of electromagnetic interactions are:

[image: Electromagnetic interactions]

We can conclude that at the quantum level, things really are different.

[6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ojti.png): Dirk Hünniger, Joel Holdsworth

[8] Tipler, P A.. ; Mosca, G.: "Física para la ciencia y la tecnología", volumen 2 (6ª edición). Ed. Reverte, 2010
[9] Serway, R.A.; Jewett, J.W.: "Física para ciencias e ingeniería con física moderna". Ed. Cengage Learning (7ª edición), 2009.
[10] Gettys, W.E.; Keller, F.J.; Skove, M.J.: "Física clásica y moderna". Ed. Mc Graw Hill, 1998
[11] Alonso, M.; Finn, E.J.: "Física" (volumen 2). Ed. Addis on Wesley Iberoamericana, 1997.
[12] Eisberg, R.M.; Lerner, L.S.: "Física: fundamentos y aplicaciones" (volume n 2). Mc Graw Hill, 1986

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you asking if positrons attract electrons, or if positrons attract positrons?

Comment: @AXensen I'm asking if electrons attract anti-electrons, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anti-particles have the opposite charge of their respective particle, i.e., electrons have a charge of -e, and positrons have a charge of e, so yes, in accordance with Coulomb's law, they would attract each other when particles and anti-particles collide, they are annihilated, and energy is released. Here is a good source of reading https://www.britannica.com/science/annihilation